# How to check out a project from version control as a specific project type in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Salesforce project in GitHub that I want to check out in IntelliJ IDEA and use this as an Illuminated Cloud project. How do I do this?

I've used Eclipse with the Force.com IDE plugin before - there you can simply choose the project type and that you want to check out from the repository in one step so I think there should be a way to do this but neither me nor my colleagues are able to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set up a project and commit IDE project files to the version control, this way anyone will be able to open and use it in IntelliJ IDEA without configuring it again, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.

Comment: While this would certainly fix the problem it will mix project files with the "real" source code. This is generally a bad idea as developers might not use the same environment and project files often contain many user-specific settings (as stated in the link) so imho checking in both is only an option for certain setups.